# Append a pandas row with data from another dataframe if a certain column matches

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes with the same columns (they represent different years of a sporting season). If a player played in both seasons, I'd like to append certain information from the following season to that season's dataframe.

DF1

| Name | PPG |
| --- | --- |
| Michael Jordan | 31.7 |

DF2

| Name | PPG |
| --- | --- |
| Michael Jordan | 28.4 |

What I'd like to do is combine them (either into DF1 or a new DF3) and have three rows

| Name | PPG | PPG Next Season |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Michael Jordan | 31.7 | 28.4 |

Not all players played in both seasons. How can I check all the players in DF1, see if they played in DF2, and if so add a new column to DF1 tracking those players DF2 PPG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Michael Jordan'], 'PPG': [31.7]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Michael Jordan'], 'PPG': [28.4]})

df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='Name', suffixes=('', ' Next Season'))

print(df3)
```

The `suffixes` parameter is used to add a suffix to the columns in `df2` to avoid duplicate column names in the merged dataframe.

| Name | PPG | PPG Next Season |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Michael Jordan | 31.7 | 28.4 |

Comment: Yep, nailed it! Thank you.